# Python Data Transformation using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataset looks like this

```
    Name
83   A
84   A
85   A
97   C
98   C
99   C
131  D
132  D
133  D
```

and going on with random index.

While the output I want is;

```
Instance Name RowID1 RowID2 RowID3
1        A    83     84     85
2        C    97     98     99
3        D    131    132    133
```

**Please note- Names and indexes are random, with no relation between them. How can I do it using Python (Pandas).

Comment: `Instance` is column?

Comment: Yes, it is a column

Comment: @mozway - seems partly dupe, so should be reopened. What do you think?

Comment: @jezrael there is probably a better dupe, but it feels like a 100 times seen use case, but sure do as you want

Answer (score 1):

First step is convert df.index to `df['index']` column by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then create helper column `g` by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) in [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), rename columns by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html).

Last use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for column `Instance`:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .assign(g = lambda x: x.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1))
        .pivot('Name', 'g', 'index')
        .add_prefix('RowID')
        .reset_index()
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1))

df.insert(0, 'Instance', range(1, len(df) + 1))
print (df)
   Instance Name  RowID1  RowID2  RowID3
0         1    A      83      84      85
1         2    C      97      98      99
2         3    D     131     132     133
```